# MusicPlayer issues in Android (Beginner)

Tags: android, audio, media-player, playback

I have an issue with an app I'm creating.

Basically, I am trying to have music playing in the background of my app, which I can do and it plays fine. However, when the user changes to another screen, the music restarts instead of just continuing as normal.

Here is all the code I have currently:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {    


MediaPlayer mp;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    //setting the layout

    mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.song);
    mp.setLooping(true);
    mp.getDuration();
    mp.start();
```

I then have this method at the end of this class to stop the music when the app is closed:

```
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPause();


    mp.release();
    finish();

}
```

I am unsure of what to include in my other classes so the music continues playing. If anyone could show me I'd be very appreciative.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have made your Mediaplayer instance dependent on the Activity. So when Activity gets restarted, onCreate() gets called again and the music restarts. If you want to continue playing music, take the mp out of any Activity instance and put it inside a Service. Then start the Service from your MainActivity and let it play the music unless you stop the Service.

```
  public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {




    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

Intent i; 
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.splash);
       i=new Intent(this, MyMusicService.class);
       final ToggleButton togglebutton =(ToggleButton)findViewById(R.id.toggleButton1);
      togglebutton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {  
          public void onClick(View v) {   
              // Perform action on clicks    
              if (togglebutton.isChecked()) {   
                  Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Checked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();  
                  startService(i);  
              } else {   
                  stopService(i);
                  Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Not checked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
                      }    }});





}
@Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onDestroy();
stopService(i);
}
}
```

The service is this :

```
   public class MyMusicService extends Service {
    MediaPlayer mp;


@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
     mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.song);


        mp.start();
mp.setLooping(true);

    return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
}


@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onDestroy();
    if(mp!=null)
        mp.release();
    mp=null;
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, however the line

super(name);

is creating errors.

Comment: what do you mean register the service ??

Comment: IN you mainfest add the line :<service android:name="MyMusicService"></service>

Comment: Yes sorry I did that, but I thought by "Register" you meant something else.

It still doesn't play. Anything else you can suggest? Apologies for my inexperience.

Comment: I have changed the implementation of Service. I forgot that Mediaplayer should be started from the main thread. Try the new service code.

Comment: Thank you, this now works perfectly. However I just have 2 more questions:

1) The music does not stop when I close the app.
2) Do you know how I can make a ToggleButton in another class (Options) which can stop and start the music?

Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: I have changed the Activity and added a toggle button. I have also put stopService in onDestro of Activity which will stop the service playing the music.

Comment: please upvote and mark it as the correct answer if it worked for you :)

Comment: I would love to, but apparently I don't have enough reputation :( I'm very sorry

Comment: check the answer as the accepted answer, you will be able to do it as it is your question. :)

Comment: in above code user can able to play the sound from raw folder. Instead  if user want to play it form the any dynamic selected path then how it will be possible.

Answer (score 0):

Put the mp.release() is the onDestroy method not in the onPause() method. Caz every time a new Activity comes to the interface the existing Activity goes to the pause state.

Comment: Thank you very much for the response. This has solved the issue of the music stopping playing. However, it's created a new issue where every time they go to a new screen and go back to the MainActivity class the music plays twice. Any ideas?